# SheetJs converting date automatically angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx, angular7, sheetjs

I'm using sheetjs in angular 7. And I'm exporting excel from my json. But excel converting my date to 02/29/2019 format. But, I'm sending "29.02.2019". I'm sending as string, excel still converting. I also send "29.02.2019." by adding "." character at end of date, but it still convert to "02/29/2019." . How can I achieve showing by my format?

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

exportExcelFromJson(jsonData): void {
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'MyExcel.xlsx');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the **dateNF** option to your call as described in the documentation: https://docs.sheetjs.com/#array-of-objects-input

so such a call should work:

```
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonData, {dateNF:"dd.MM.yyyy"});
```

Comment: as in no change to date structure or is it throwing an error?

Comment: can you try setting the cellDates option to true.

Comment: Thanks. `dateNF` worked now. For working `dateNF` , json property should be written as Date. I wrote as string and then it's not worked. But excel converting whatever you write string or date. @ChiragPatel

Comment: I am using same code, but in my case I am expecting that date should be right aligned and It should be visible as a dat currently it is visible as General. How can we achieve that?  Code is same as question asked.